# Why does the CMake command show "The source directory "/home/shubham" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt."?

Tags: cmake, openkinect, kinect-v2, libfreenect2, cmake-server

I am installing libfreenect2 on Linux.

I am following the steps given in https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2.

Command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/freenect2"
```

gives me an error:

> "CMake Error: The source directory "/home/shubham" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

When I searched for "CMakeLists.txt" file, it is in the libfreenect2 folder.

Comment: So the first argument to `cmake` (`..`) should point to the directory which contains `CMakeLists.txt`. Probably, you forgot to create `build/` subdirectory in your project and going (`cd`) into it. (In other words, this line from the manual: `mkdir build && cd build` should be performed from the root directory of the project, which contains `CMakeLists.txt` file).

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you tell me what does "You need to specify cmake -Dfreenect2_DIR=$HOME/freenect2/lib/cmake/freenect2 for CMake based third-party application to find libfreenect2." this means?

Comment: You are installing `freenect2` which is **library**, so it is usefull only for other project, which uses this library. For such project, if it is written using CMake and uses `find_package(freenect2)` for work with the library, you should pass given argument to `cmake`. See also documentation for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html) command.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev